# Asymptotic analysis for a fraction of two integrals.

Tags: integration, asymptotics

Consider a function:
$\frac{\int_0^{2R}x^2\left(1-\left(1-\frac{S(x;R)}{\pi R^2}\right)^n\right)dx}{\int_0^{2R}x\left(1-\left(1-\frac{S(x;R)}{\pi R^2}\right)^n\right)dx}$ where
$S(x;R)=2R^2\arccos{\frac{x}{2R}}-\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{4R^2-x^2}$ for $x<2R$.

When $n$ goes to infinity, does the result converge to $\frac{\int_0^{2R} x^2dx}{\int_0^{2R} xdx}$? Since $\left(1-\frac{S(x;R)}{\pi R^2}\right)^{n}$ would converge to $0$?

Answer (score 1):

On both integrals you can use [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), if you are not familiarized with measure theory, you can use the following: if $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ uniformly (i.e. $\sup_{x \in \left[a,b\right]}\left|f_{n}\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right)\right| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$) then

$\int_{a}^{b} f_{n}\left(x\right) dx \to \int_{a}^{b} f\left(x\right)dx$
as $n \to \infty$

(this is a really common analysis exercise and it is not hard). Both approaches shows that the fraction in question converges to

$\frac{\int_{0}^{2R}x^{2} dx}{\int_{0}^{2R} xdx} = \frac{\frac{\left(2R\right)^
3}{3}}{\frac{\left(2R\right)^{2}}{2}} = \frac{4R}{3}$.